# dual boot problem windows 10 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

My computer : HP Elitebook Windows 10 Pro
I have created a dual boot with ubuntu 20-04 LTS
I cannot boot anymore on windows.
I have tried boot-repair without success
I have tried to repair the bcd with HirenBootcd tools : without success
Here is the pastebin with the needed info (I hope)
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YB2s6cRFQY/

TIA for your kind help
Dirko

Comment: Have you tried changing the boot mode in BIOS to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy Mode?

Comment: Windows needs UEFI, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @kanehekili - You're mistaken.  The Ubuntu install should *match* the existing Windows installation. In this case, it appears that Windows is already installed in MBR/Compatibility mode. This is atypical these days but not unusual.  OP should attempt to boot the installation media in BIOS/MBR/Compatibility mode.  Another alternative is to format the disk as GPT and reinstall both operating systems in UEFI mode

Comment: @Nmath- thanks for clearing this up. I thought that Windows 10 needs UEFI, while Win8 does not. But your're right about "matching" - therefore I thought if Win10 then UEFI, then Linux must be installed the same

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find Windows boot manager in the grub menu, `sudo update-grub` should fix it.